# Predicting probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, probability, prediction

I have time series data consisting of a vector

```
v=(x_1,…, x_n)
```

of binary categorical variables and the probabilities for four outcomes

```
p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4.
```

Given a new vector of categorical variables I want to predict the probabilities

```
p_1,…,p_4
```

The probabilities are very unbalanced with

```
p_1>.99 and p_2, p_3, p_4 < .01.
```

For example

```
v_1= (1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0) , p_1=.99, p_2=.005, p_3=.0035, p_4= .0015 
v_2=(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1), p_1=.99, p_2=.006, p_3=.0035, p_4= .0005
v_3=(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0), p_1=.99, p_2=.005, p_3=.003, p_4= .002
v_4=(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1), p_1=.99, p_2=.0075, p_3=.002, p_4= .0005
```

Given a new vector

```
v_5= (0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0)
```

I want to predict

```
p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4.
```

I should also note that the new vector could be identical to one of the input vectors, i.e.,

```
v_5=(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1)= v_4.
```

My initial approach is to turn this into 4 regression problems.

The first would predict p_1, the second would predict p_2, the third would predict p_3, and the fourth would predict p_4. The problem with this is that I need

```
p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=1
```

I’m not classifying, but should I also be worried about the unbalanced probabilities. Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: What is the relation between outcomes and probabilities ??

Comment: @rpd, I’ll do my best to describe. The probabilities are associated with dinning frequency among a sample. During a one week period in time and a  sample of 100,000 people in California,  999,900 people did not eat at a McDonalds in Bakersfield, 60 people ate a McDonalds in Bakersfield once, 30 people dinned twice, 10 people ate three times.

Comment: The probabilities are really straightforward. What about the vector? What does it represent? What is the vector length ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion of considering this as a multiple problem + final normalization, has some sense, but it's known to be problematic in many cases (see, e.g., the problem of [masking](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat857/node/72)).

What you're describing here is [multiclass (soft) classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification), and there are many many known techniques for doing so. You didn't specify which language/tool/library you're using, or if you're planning on rolling your own (which only makes sense for didactic purposes). I'd suggest starting with [Linear Discriminant Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) which is very simple to understand and implement, and - despite its strong assumptions - is known to often work well in practice (see [the classical book by Hastie & Tibshirani](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)).

---

Irrespective of the underlying algorithm you use for soft binary classification (e.g., LDA or not), It is not very difficult to transform aggregate input into labeled input.

Consider for example the instance

```
v_1= (1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0) , p_1=.99, p_2=.005, p_3=.0035, p_4= .0015
```

If your classifier supports instance weights, feed it 4 instances, labeled 1, 2, ..., with weights given by *p_1*, *p_2*, ..., respectively.

If it does not support instance weights, simply simulate what the law of large numbers says would happen: generate some large *n* instance from this input; for each such new input, choose a label randomly proportionally to its probability.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have individual records and their class labels only the aggregated data with the percentage in each class. I usually use the machine learning libraries in R.

Comment: @mikeL I don't think the aggregate inputs are much of an issue; see the update.